# How to remove Id attribute on Reference in digital signature Java

Tags: java, xml, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate

Used below dependancy for create digitial signature

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to create digital signature using

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

But after the digital signature creating process it output not i'm expected xml referance
Here's the output

```
<ds:Reference Id="cid:aseXML" URI="#cid:aseXML">
```

Here the whole output xml when create the signature

```
------=_Part_0_728269496.1684211247325
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Id: 
<soappart>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"
        xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ file:packages/WmebXML/config/init/schemas/msg_1_0/envelope.xsd http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader file:packages/WmebXML/config/init/schemas/msg_1_0/messageHeaderv0_99.xsd">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
                <eb:From>
                    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:frchub.net">XXX</eb:PartyId>
                </eb:From>
                <eb:To>
                    <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:frchub.net">XXX</eb:PartyId>
                </eb:To>
                <eb:CPAId>XXX</eb:CPAId>
                <eb:ConversationId>XXX XXX 781181f1-549f-43ac-b069-cff842120197</eb:ConversationId>
                <eb:Service eb:type="fbs">MediumPriorityAseXMLDocument</eb:Service>
                <eb:Action>MDMT</eb:Action>
                <eb:MessageData>
                    <eb:MessageId>XXX 781181f1-549f-43ac-b069-cff842120197</eb:MessageId>
                    <eb:Timestamp>2023-05-16T14:27:27+10:00</eb:Timestamp>
                    <eb:TimeToLive>2023-05-16T17:27:27+10:00</eb:TimeToLive>
                </eb:MessageData>
                <eb:QualityOfServiceInfo eb:deliverySemantics="OnceAndOnlyOnce"/>
            </eb:MessageHeader>
            <eb:TraceHeaderList eb:version="1.0" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
                <eb:TraceHeader>
                    <eb:Sender>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:frchub.net">XXX</eb:PartyId>
                        <eb:Location>https://gashub-prod.sumo.com.au:5326/invoke/wm.ip.ebxml.MSH/receive</eb:Location>
                    </eb:Sender>
                    <eb:Receiver>
                        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:frchub.net">RELAY</eb:PartyId>
                        <eb:Location>https://preprod.frchub.net:5319/invoke/relay/inbound</eb:Location>
                    </eb:Receiver>
                    <eb:Timestamp>2023-05-16T14:27:27+10:00</eb:Timestamp>
                </eb:TraceHeader>
            </eb:TraceHeaderList>
            <eb:Via eb:ackRequested="Signed" eb:version="1.0" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"/>
            <ds:Signature Id="WmEbXML-Signature-54cl6h00gi08isbf003ient2">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::eb:TraceHeaderList or ancestor-or-self::eb:Via)</ds:XPath>
                            </ds:Transform>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>L1NiK7K8gy44ubM1WagOkAfyXuI=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    **<ds:Reference Id="cid:aseXML" URI="#cid:aseXML">**
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>49kdKnmdhzC0wBF8L9sKMX32G1o=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>XzyXevY00aJlo+sSj2wNpbO9mFQp7ML136b0guGSmyt/8nZRff/cB5MrAHDAU7hOnqwmNd8XBNwz7/djrgVumFvbPROSEgX2b6izXkc2f6mqlslWYtjMPb/vv6PGvok0ugu3ajRdcpuK1awHD0rp4zyKEpPLDxA4z0EMclLL9nKEtGV09VRoQoFpefkYA3t8pgdSdXdQGoZLXwTvamDMQLmi0KUfryRVKshk9P4S3jZFSZbiiexjIE1asm2nR0xP/F1J4U8b3/Ef+5G2BuAW758MVbJi78LFjrsRB2VDIueQzih3BTi/+CfJ8p7Eg1IjrUUk9/8X2qUtedbygP1FSw==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <ds:KeyValue>
                        <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                            <ds:Modulus>tEwpS7E66OGOtjRmxF/n2WhRtSG4fX1plZWOMC6muIQKRmNeZ4R1rIhWN9/ApIvnU2s3ydV6EuYxXwgg6Dj+rFqLyD4ad5kpe4iValJw6+iUgNsdPXeX4nyzSyjrYwqXBWcJ1PySuVjN4fGI20M/9UBN6p35N/7SQhkrx9Hrj+y/sIZj33SDLrqw79HeoTbah1aL8V4Ah02tYQi20qRAsyM1dz3czuzCdvA2flQFlWJsX0NEFFyDfbOEQk6ZbeWYdbSHxYvEjWy0A0EQ2bfBog0A/ulVCMY8VFHVohcVi6+jwmHq6rFezTKnDeCaY9fL9/1n07CjEOzDvYJp5FlfSw==</ds:Modulus>
                            <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                        </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                    </ds:KeyValue>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509SubjectName>XXX</ds:X509SubjectName>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>MIIFAzCCA+ugAwIBAgIQD8BrY2+s1N8STrkTMhU63zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTEyMDAGA1UEChMpQXVzdHJhbGlhbiBFbmVyZ3kgTWFya2V0IE9wZXJhdG9yIExpbWl0ZWQxGTAXBgNVBAMTEEFFTU8tSUNBLVRFU1QgRzEwHhcNMjMwMjE3MDAwMDAwWhcNMjYwMjE1MjM1OTU5WjBbMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTERMA8GA1UECBMIVmljdG9yaWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCU1lbGJvdXJuZTENMAsGA1UEChMEQUVNTzEWMBQGA1UEAxMNU1VNTzItUHJlUHJvZDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALRMKUuxOujhjrY0ZsRf59loUbUhuH19aZWVjjAupriECkZjXmeEdayIVjffwKSL51NrN8nVehLmMV8IIOg4/qxai8g+GneZKXuIlWpScOvolIDbHT13l+J8s0so62MKlwVnCdT8krlYzeHxiNtDP/VATeqd+Tf+0kIZK8fR64/sv7CGY990gy66sO/R3qE22odWi/FeAIdNrWEIttKkQLMjNXc93M7swnbwNn5UBZVibF9DRBRcg32zhEJOmW3lmHW0h8WLxI1stANBENm3waINAP7pVQjGPFRR1aIXFYuvo8Jh6uqxXs0ypw3gmmPXy/f9Z9OwoxDsw72CaeRZX0sCAwEAAaOCAcAwggG8MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFLObeJREzHBITOulhDEDmNo2+ssEMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTYcw2iSBrmnKmkVG6hk2JvCVaOUzAYBgNVHREEETAPgg1TVU1PMi1QcmVQcm9kMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwbQYDVR0fBGYwZDAwoC6gLIYqaHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0FFTU9JQ0FURVNURzEuY3JsMDCgLqAshipodHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQUVNT0lDQVRFU1RHMS5jcmwwQQYDVR0gBDowODA2BglghkgBhv1sAQEwKTAnBggrBgEFBQcCARYbaHR0cDovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMHEGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGUwYzAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMDsGCCsGAQUFBzAChi9odHRwOi8vY2FjZXJ0cy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQUVNTy1JQ0EtVEVTVEcxLmNydDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCrrec8+7laWuMzxvmws/80dtdVKmwTTF/qXFy3k3ONDNqcfQteXjKxH83VFxi9rgKSt07HG2HWzUnOzK4WSJ4Lwr/Af01Ycxy5zblSzfl/9A0yjgyX9rxFnRYtLYr8EqMXt18N1jdd+YH9L0P8j+SKfdzm5C1tLTlWV2fKppaE2xjmYw3Bj4g8xG+bhaNR/sFXzp2NApovBjdsfh2BjBw1gXDdSKjh8OE2/zEW7RcilwjDw8+8vJAEs1XQnc9zU1OiheWSdAjPXhxTtlGmcwKBqo8Gi75rTd2wxk747oIiSKBjCVsLgdKu12RZGDmvH4vr3a/9P6VkyrHVuM5DGaFC</ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <eb:Manifest eb:version="1.0">
                <eb:Reference eb:id="aseXML" xlink:href="cid:aseXML" xlink:type="simple">
                    <eb:Schema eb:location="urn:aseXML:r40 http://www.nemmco.com.au/aseXML/schemas/r40/aseXML_r40.xsd" eb:version="r40"/>
                </eb:Reference>
            </eb:Manifest>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
------=_Part_0_728269496.1684211247325
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-ID: 
    <aseXML>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


        <ase:aseXML xsi:schemaLocation="urn:aseXML:r40 http://www.nemmco.com.au/aseXML/schemas/r40/aseXML_r40.xsd"
            xmlns:ase="urn:aseXML:r40"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Header>
                <From>XXX</From>
                <To>XXX</To>
                <MessageID>XXX</MessageID>
                <MessageDate>2023-04-26T11:59:10+10:00</MessageDate>
                <TransactionGroup>XXX</TransactionGroup>
                <Priority>Medium</Priority>
                <Market>XXX</Market>
            </Header>
            <Transactions>
                <Transaction transactionID="KHG-TNS-20230426115829915118" transactionDate="2023-04-26T11:58:29+10:00">
                    <NMIDiscoveryRequest version="r17">
                        <JurisdictionCode>WGI</JurisdictionCode>
                        <Address>
                            <StructuredAddress>
                                <House>
                                    <HouseNumber>7</HouseNumber>
                                </House>
                                <Street>
                                    <StreetName>XXX</StreetName>
                                    <StreetType>XXX</StreetType>
                                </Street>
                            </StructuredAddress>
                            <SuburbOrPlaceOrLocality>XXX</SuburbOrPlaceOrLocality>
                            <StateOrTerritory>NSW</StateOrTerritory>
                            <PostCode>6112</PostCode>
                        </Address>
                    </NMIDiscoveryRequest>
                </Transaction>
            </Transactions>
        </ase:aseXML>
------=_Part_0_728269496.1684211247325--
```

Check this part in above xml

**<ds:Reference Id="cid:aseXML" URI="#cid:aseXML">**

I expected this xml line like below

**<ds:Reference URI="cid:aseXML">**

```
public SOAPMessage addSignature(Resource keyStoreFile, String keyStorePassword, String keyStoreAlias, SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws Exception {

        Field f = XMLUtils.class.getDeclaredField("ignoreLineBreaks");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(null, Boolean.TRUE);

        //create basic structure of signature
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        File attachedFile = new File("C:\\Resources\\ase2.xml");
        Element element = null;
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(printSOAPResponse(soapMessage))));

        Init.init();
        org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature sig =
            new org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature(doc, null, SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1);

        element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        element.normalize();
        element.getElementsByTagName("SOAP-ENV:Header").item(0).appendChild(sig.getElement());

        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
        transforms.addTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.ENVELOPED);

        String xpathExpr = "not(ancestor-or-self::eb:TraceHeaderList or ancestor-or-self::eb:Via)";

        XPathContainer xpathContainer = new XPathContainer(doc);
        xpathContainer.setXPath(xpathExpr);

        // Add the XPath transform to the Transforms object
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_XPATH, xpathContainer.getElement());

        transforms.addTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE);

        ResolverLocalFilesystem fileResolver = new ResolverLocalFilesystem();
        ResourceResolver.register(fileResolver, false);

        //Sign the content of SOAP Envelope
        sig.addDocument("", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);

        //Adding the attachment to be signed
        //sig.addDocument(attachedFile.toURI().toURL().toString(), null, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
        **sig.getSignedInfo().addDocument(attachedFile.getPath(), "#cid:aseXML", null, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1, "cid:aseXML", null);**

        // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile.getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
            (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry
                (keyStoreAlias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray()));

        X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
        sig.setId("WmEbXML-Signature-54cl6h00gi08isbf003ient2");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
        sig.addKeyInfo(publicKey);

        org.apache.xml.security.keys.content.X509Data x509Data = new org.apache.xml.security.keys.content.X509Data(doc);

        // create an XMLX509SubjectName object and set the subject name
        XMLX509SubjectName subjectName = new XMLX509SubjectName(doc, x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        x509Data.add(subjectName);
        x509Data.addCertificate(x509Certificate);

        org.apache.xml.security.keys.KeyInfo keyInfo = sig.getKeyInfo();
        keyInfo.add(x509Data);

        sig.sign(keyEntry.getPrivateKey());
        
        DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();

        LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput lsOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
        lsOutput.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        lsOutput.setCharacterStream(stringWriter);
        lsSerializer.write(doc, lsOutput);
        String content = stringWriter.toString();

        SOAPMessage message = toSOAPMessage(content);

        return message;
    }
```

I change this method so many ways
**sig.getSignedInfo().addDocument(attachedFile.getPath(), "#cid:aseXML", null, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1, "cid:aseXML", null);**

But no luck.

Please give any suggestion for this kind of issue